# How do you add a margin around the screen in a Navigation based iOS application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm playing around with an iOS project in Xcode, I've created a new navigation based application, and I'm curious of something. Is it possible to add a margin around the screen, so that the navigation bar, table and toolbar have a few pixels on the top, bottom, left and right? The purpose would be for the entire view of the application to not be 100% of the width and height of the screen, maybe only 95% of each. Not sure if I'm using the right terminology, I'll try to clarify if necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: it's hard to explain, but the mockup i'm working with has 2 rounded corners at the top of the navigation bar and bottom of the toolbar. because of the rounded corners, i need to shave about 5 pixels off the left and right of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I just didn't ask the question sensibly, but since I can't find an answer, I'm just going to create custom images for navigation bar and toolbar using black space for the margin, and use another question's answer in regards to shortening the width of the UITableViewCells.